# Getting a large amount of data from an API returns errors

Tags: c#

I am calling an API which returns a large amount of data (almost 1Go of records). In my code I serialize the HttpWebResponse into JSON format (see code below). First everything works fine because the amount of data wasn't large but now the number of records is increased and I start getting errors (Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 798180005 bytes). Any help please!

```
string _URL = "https://www.mysrvices.com/api/getData";

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_URL);
request.Headers.Add("Token", myToken.ToString());
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
var _serialisedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

//File to save my Json result.
string fileName = "ListData.json";
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine("C:\", fileName), _serialisedJson);
Console.WriteLine("Done  !!");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Most web services put a pagination service in place to prevent stuff like this from happening. My question is, why are you deserialising the JSON only to send it back out to JSON as text in a file? Why not just directly write the response to a file (via a stream so you don't reserve a ton of memory)? What does deserialisation and re-serialisation achieve for you here?

Comment: Is it happening while Deserialization or GetResponse() from server?

Comment: _"What does deserialisation and re-serialisation achieve for you here"_ - I believe the intent is to format the Json (`Formatting.Indented`)

Comment: Don't do this. `new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();`. Write the Stream directly to disc. Don't store it in a string varable. Otherwise, not only you have 1GB od data in `responseString`, but also in `parsedJson` and in `_serialisedJson`. Your app will never survive.

Comment: The reason why I'm deserializing and serializing is to have an intdented json file, because otherwise my json file will contain only one line with all records. The error occurs here : var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Comment: You don't need to indent a JSON. That format is only used for presentation, it's more readable, for a human. It's totally unneeded and counter-productive when a machine is reading it. Save the stream to disc immediately, while you're downloading it. First problem solved. Now, you have to learn how to deserialize it using a JsonReader, to perform a partial deserialization of the content. Otherwise, you're back to memory shortage as soon as you try to access the full content all at once.